# Managed Package Post Install Script failure

Tags: apex, managed-package, postinstall

My post-install script is failing on just one sandbox, and I can't figure out why. It has been working successfully for more than a year, on a number of different orgs, but this one fails. When it fails, I don't get any other details beyond the simple message "The post install script failed."

Here's my script:

```
public without sharing class ApiInstallHandler implements InstallHandler, UninstallHandler {

    public void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
        ApiSentinelRunLaterScheduled.scheduleSelf('');
    }

    public void onUninstall(UninstallContext context) {
        ApiSentinelRunLaterScheduled.cancelSelf('');
    }
}
```

And then, the dependent class:

```
// Sweeps up any sentinels that we couldn't start because they were
// triggered from a Batch or Future context. Time-based workflow
// would make more sense, but cannot be added to a managed package
public class ApiSentinelRunLaterScheduled implements Schedulable {

    private static String jobName = 'API Sentinel Run Later';

    public void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        NebulaApiWorker.runLaterWorkers();
    }

    public static void cancelSelf(String namePrefix) {
        List<CronTrigger> existingToCancel = [SELECT Id, CronJobDetail.Name, State 
                                              FROM CronTrigger 
                                              WHERE CronJobDetail.Name LIKE :namePrefix + jobName + '%'
                                              AND CronJobDetail.JobType = '7' 
                                              AND State != 'DELETED'];

        for(CronTrigger t : existingToCancel) {
            System.abortJob(t.Id);
        }


    }  

    public static void scheduleSelf(String namePrefix) {
        cancelSelf(namePrefix);

        ApiSentinelRunLaterScheduled asr = new ApiSentinelRunLaterScheduled();

        // every 15 minutes
        for(integer i=0; i < 4; i++) {
            String minutes = '' + (i*15);
            System.schedule(namePrefix + jobName + ' (' + minutes + ')', '0 ' + minutes + ' * * * ?', asr);
        }
    }        
}
```

Any ideas about how I can attack this? One obvious thing is to make a version of the package with a try..catch and then log the errors. But is there anything else to try before I go through that laborious process?

Comment: Code should work. The only difference between orgs (if it works for some and does not work for some) is the data, in your case - `CronTrigger` table. Try clearing it in the problematic org, also, try running this code manually on the org

Comment: Thanks, but I'd already checked the CronTrigger table, and I tried running the body of cancelSelf() in the dev console - neither has helper. I can't run the rest of it because the classes are not global, and I don't want to make them permanently global just for this. I think I'm going to have to add some logging and see if that helps :(

Comment: Logging is always good. But can't you run the rest of the code from executeAnonimous?

Comment: It's not global, so nope, can't run it.

Comment: I mean just run this: 
        // every 15 minutes
        for(integer i=0; i < 4; i++) {
            String minutes = '' + (i*15);
            System.schedule(namePrefix + jobName + ' (' + minutes + ')', '0 ' + minutes + ' * * * ?', asr);
        } from Execute Anonimous in dev console

Comment: ApiSentinelRunLaterScheduled is not global, so you can't make an instance of it, so the lines you're saying to run make no sense without an instance of asr.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I didn't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've logged the error during the post-install and it is:

> The Apex job named "API Sentinel Run Later (0)" is already scheduled
>   for execution.
>   Class.Nebula_Api.ApiSentinelRunLaterScheduled.scheduleSelf: line 34,
>   column 1 Class.Nebula_Api.NebulaApiInstallHandler.onInstall: line 5,
>   column 1

So, I ran this in the dev console:

```
List<CronTrigger> triggers = [SELECT Id, CronJobDetail.Name, State FROM Crontrigger ALL ROWS];

for(CronTrigger ct : triggers) {
    System.debug(ct.CronJobDetail.Name + ': ' + ct);
}
```

Which gives the following debug output (just one row):

> 09:46:39:009 USER_DEBUG
>   [4]|DEBUG|pi_Async_Request_Scheduler-1503878362374:
>   CronTrigger:{Id=08e4E0000074VEvQAM,
>   CronJobDetailId=08a4E0000074W5VQAU, State=WAITING}

Which seems to mean that there's a phantom instance of the scheduled job already recorded in the sandbox. I can't find it, so I can't cancel it. Which looks like an interaction between two known issues:

1. AsyncApexJob row for Scheudled Apex Jobs is not sandbox copied https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008Ym6AAE
2. [Scheduled batch "already scheduled"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32011/scheduled-batch-already-scheduled)

So, the solution is to throw the current time in ms on to the end of the scheduled job name. Interestingly, if you look at the debug output from what I tried above, you can see that Pardot are doing this for their scheduled job!

Comment: How did you manage to log the error and see those logs?

Comment: I am super curious about that too! As far as I know there is no way to see debug logs generated by a managed package in the post install script.