# Apex Scheduled jobs stopped executing unexpectedly

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

We have 2 scheduled jobs which are executing hourly basis in our app. In few of our client's org, they stopped executing unexpectedly.

They are shown in Setup->Monitoring->Scheduled Jobs

But, the next scheduled run of both the jobs is null.

What can be the reason of this kind of behavior?

Thanks,
Rupali

Comment: Are these recurring scheduled jobs, or does the job schedule another one on completion? The latter approach can be prone to dropping off - See [Scheduled batch jobs and durability](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/13069/102)